# Jenkins 2.7 launch all jobs starting with a keyword as pipeline

Tags: automation, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to launch all jobs starting with a preset string as a pipeline in Jenkins 2.7. So far I managed to write this groovy code:

```
node {
    jobs = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getAllItems(FreeStyleProject)
for (job in jobs) {
      // here was an "if" statement: if (job.getFullName() =~ /my regex/) {
      stage job.getFullName()
      build job: job.getFullName(), propagate: false
  }
 }
}
```

However on every launch I get `java.io.NotSerializableException`, and only one job matching (out of two at this time) is being executed.

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, how I would do that:

```
import hudson.model.*;

// get all jobs which exists    
jobs = Hudson.instance.getAllItems(FreeStyleProject);

// iterate through the jobs
for (j in jobs) {

  // define a pattern, which jobs I do not want to run
  def pattern = 'trunk';
  def m = j.getName() =~ pattern;

  // if pattern does not match, then run the job
  if (!m) {
    // first check, if job is buildable
    if (j instanceof BuildableItem) {
      // run that job
      j.scheduleBuild();
    }
  }
}
```

I commented my code, so this should help you.

Comment: Thank you, this way it actually triggers said jobs, however using `obj.scheduleBuild()`, build time and state is not returned to the pipeline view. It seems I need to use pipeline's `build` function, but it throws me an exception...